# @EJB annotation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

```
@EJB SomeEJBLocal audit ;
```

I am wondering if this Annotation @EJB works on all App Servers ?  (Assuming that the App Servers do Implement J2EE spec)
or does it work only on GlassFish AppServer ?

Answer (score 5):

`@EJB` is part of the JavaEE 5 spec.  Any JavaEE-5-compliant application server will support it, no exceptions.